# Sending Emails from nodejs app using Nodemailer and Gmail SMTP

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail, nodemailer

I've successfully created an endpoint on my express app to send an Email from an HTML form element using Nodemailer and Gmail SMTP.

I know it's not preferable to send emails using Gmail but since it is my portfolio and I will be receiving a minimal amount of emails I thought I won't need to configure an email server.

and Actually, **it works** with my Gmail, I successfully send the main email from the sender's email to my Gmail, and another email from my email to the sender's as an auto-reply.

the thing is in my Gmail client's inbox I can't see the sender's email and I see my email instead although the message has successfully been sent to the sender - "Mohamedkareem@gmail.com" in this example - [image]

despite sending the email from the sender's email which came from the HTML form

```
const options = {
    from: `${name} <${email}>`,
    to: "islamabdelhakiim21@gmail.com",
    subject: subject,
    html: message,
};
```

I believe this is because the authentication is made by my email, so it sends from my email anyway.

```
 const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "islamabdelhakiim21@gmail.com",
      pass: "jtrybohpvsnfggzm",
    },
  });
```

So is there any solution to have the sender's email as the sender and appearing in the "from" in my Gmail,
or should I use another approach?